# How can I trace an image to generate an SVG pattern?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, svg

I have an image (in jpg and svg format) that I'd like to generate a pattern I can use as a fill for an SVG image I am working on. Is there any tool or technique to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just put the image (jpg or svg) in a pattern.

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="image1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image xlink:href="image.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

Then you can use it as a fill attribute like this:  fill="url(#image1)" />